# Invoking a 'REST' service which have query parameters in the URL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, web-client

I have to invoke a GET on a service which returns `text/xml`.

The endpoint is something like this:

```
http://service.com/rest.asp?param1=34&param2=88&param3=foo
```

When I hit this url directly on a browser (or some UI tool), all's good. I get a response.

Now, I am trying to use `CXF WebClient` to fetch the result using a piece of code like this:

```
String path = "rest.asp?param1=34&param2=88&param3=foo";

webClient.path(path)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE)
    .get(Response.class);
```

I was debugging the code and found that the request being sent was url encoded which appears something like this:

```
http://service.com/rest.asp%3Fparam1=34%26param2=88%26param3=foo
```

Now, the problem is the server doesn't seem to understand this request with encoded stuff. It throws a 404. Hitting this encoded url on the browser also results in a 404.

What should I do to be able to get a response successfully (or not let the WebClient encode the url)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify the parameters using the query method:

```
String path = "rest.asp";
webClient.path(path)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE)
    .query("param1","34")
    .query("param2","88")
    .query("param3","foo")
    .get(Response.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. This is exactly what I needed. I looked at and intended to use .query but misinterpreted the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encode your URL. You can do it with the URLEncoder class as shown below:

Please replace your line

```
String path = "rest.asp?param1=34&param2=88&param3=foo";
```

with

```
String path = URLEncoder.encode("rest.asp?param1=34&param2=88&param3=foo");
```